# PHP redirect page and Echo data for get string

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code to redirect my page

I need to echo a section that was drawn from previous page to assist with the redirecting

```
//Sleep for five seconds.
sleep(5);

//Redirect using the Location header.
header('Location: case_management.php?id=<? echo $rows['case_id']; ?>');
//Post reply drawn
$sla_client = $_POST['sla_client'];
$case_id = $_POST['case_id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
```

It is giving me Unexpected case_id. This I presume is happening due to the echo side of my string. Any assistance would be appreciated

The case_id is drawn from a previous page using POST and I am trying to use that information to redirect the page from the POST reply on this page. I know my above code is trying to look for a row in the database but this will not be found this way. Any suggestion to how to use the POST reply to use in the URL

Comment: Your syntax itself is incorrect, `header('Location: case_management.php?id='.$rows['case_id']);`

Comment: You're in PHP already, so a big hint is that you don;t need to call echo. You can just use it directly (although you *may* need double quotes. I don't remember exactly.

Comment: @Manav tried yours but still not sending it to the URL

Comment: is $rows['case_id']; this contains some data from database?

Comment: @MohitKumar no it is information that was drawn from a form from a previous pages, this information I used to update a database, but want to use it to redirect me to a page with the Same ID

Comment: "*still not sending it*" are yo u looking for a `$_GET` or a `$_POST` variable?

Comment: @Manav $_GET variable

Comment: @JamesWright please shows us what is contains $rows['case_id'];???

Comment: I am trying to pull information from my database using $rows, I see now that will not work as I am not looking for the information from the database but from the POST from the previous page.

Comment: @JamesWright you tried my answer???

Comment: @MohitKumar yes tried it also gives me a blank result on the id=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened a php tag inside another already opened php tag.
I corrected your code.

```
//Sleep for five seconds.
sleep(5);

//Redirect using the Location header.
header('Location: case_management.php?id=' . $rows['case_id']);
//Post reply drawn
$sla_client = $_POST['sla_client'];
$case_id = $_POST['case_id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
```

Comment: Your code does not return error's but it also does not give the desired URL leaves the 178 out totally case_management.php?id=

Comment: perhaps the $rows['case_id'] is empty when the code is running. vardump the  $rows['case_id'] to see what is its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: case_management.php?id=".$rows['case_id']);
```

access value with `$_GET['id']`

if not, dump `$rows['case_id']` first and check to errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$getVariable = $rows['case_id'];
  header("Location:case_management.php?id=".urlencode("$getVariable"));
```